# Vue2: Subroutes Interfere with App?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have built a Vue2 SPA which runs fine at `localhost`. The server is a different matter as it runs at `https://yeoldedomain.com/apps/vueproject/`.

Initially hitting anything other than the exact starting directory (including `https://yeoldedomain.com/apps/vueproject/sign-in`) results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. Navigation is fine if you start at the starting directory, but it causes major issues with refreshing, for example.

I have configured `base: '/apps/vueproject/'` for the [`VueRouter`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base).

I realize that there may be extra complications here with Apache or other server configs, but is there anything at the app level that I'm missing?

Comment: It would be useful if you provided some actual code to better understand what the issue is. From what your question says, it's very clear you have a syntax error somewhere (unexpected token <), probably in your sign-in component, but it's hard to say where without some actual proper code.

Comment: The syntax issue isn't an issue if the app is initialized correctly (i.e. `https://yeoldedomain.com/apps/vueproject`) so I'm thinking it's something else?

Comment: If you app complains about "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", then there is one. End of story.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Sadly, it's a large app and I have no idea how to find the relevant code to include in the post. It only happens post-build (and in a specific environment), so it could be anywhere.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464951/vuejs-2-nodejs-and-reload-page?rq=1 - If you're retrieving JSON from somewhere, that might be the issue. Unless you post more code, people can't help you much.